# Searching in auto generated files with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing for Android and I am trying to fix some spam in my logs. I have the following messages coming up:

"ResourceType(14810): Skipping entry 0x1060003 in package table 0 because it is not complex!"

I am trying to fix this based on [this](http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.in/2010/12/skipping-entry-in-package-table-0.html) article. The problem is that I have many projects on my workspace and many packages and projects needed to run my application, so I don't know which R.java file (which are auto generated) to look in for entry 0x1060003.

Is there a way in Eclipse to search for this value in all the R.java files in the workspace? The ctrl+h search isn't searching in the auto generated files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search->File...

- For "File name patterns", enter "R.java"
- Check the "Consider derived resources" option (this will include generated files in the search)
- Change "Scope" to "Workspace"

Comment: Thank you! The "Consider derived resources" was the key for me.